# Objects Passed to ParameterizedThreadStart being overwritten?

Tags: c#, multithreading

**Background:**

I'm working on a small app that will read Events from an Eventlog remotely via WMI. Basically I'm searching for when a workstation locks and unlocks.

**Problem:**

I create an array of threads. I loop through my dataset (computernames) and fire off multiple 
ParameterizedThreadStart objects with a custom object (LockHunterArgs). The problem is that I know my dataset doesn't have duplicates in it. I added a console.writeline to the end of the thread function and it displays duplicates.

Also, before I tried using threads. If I ran the code synchronously it functioned fine. It just took a long time. So that's why I'm trying to introduce multithreading.

**Example Output:**

//...Snipped some unique lines above

Computer: COMP  Time: 3/29/2012 8:05:11 AM Session: 3935dd76-6a10-41a9-bd96-86143c66482d
Computer: COMP  Time: 3/29/2012 8:05:11 AM Session: 3935dd76-6a10-41a9-bd96-86143c66482d

//...Snipped some unique and duplicated lines below

**My Hypothesis:**

If I place a breakpoint in the first few lines of the get_lock_data function where it is casting and step to the next line. It is random. It will step forward once then hit the same line twice. I have even seen it go two lines down then go backwards. I assume that this is because I'm firing off threads and it is hitting the points at different times giving the illusion that it is going backwards. But it is almost like the object that is being passed in is being overwritten by later threads.

I tried creating another array of LockHunterArgs and creating and assigning them during the thread firing process but that also didn't work.

It is probably something dumb. Thanks in advance.

// lance

**Code:**

```
    public class LockHunterArgs
    {
        public LockHunterArgs(string comp, DateTime limit, Guid session)
        {
            Computer = comp;
            LimitTime = limit;
            sessionID = session;
        }
        public string Computer;
        public DateTime LimitTime;
        public Guid sessionID;
    }

    public class LockHunter
    {
        private void get_lock_data(object args)
        {
            string computer = ((LockHunterArgs)args).Computer;
            DateTime limitTime = ((LockHunterArgs)args).LimitTime;
            Guid sessionID = ((LockHunterArgs)args).sessionID;

            //....SNippet ... code connects to the box and pulls data...

            Console.WriteLine("Computer: " + computer + "  Time: " + limitTime.ToString() + " Session: " + sessionID.ToString());
        }

        public void HuntLocks()
        {
            //....Snippet... code connects to database and gets a list of objects (currentSessions)
            Thread[] threadArray = new Thread[currentSessions.Count];
            int cnt = 0;
            foreach (LINQ.session sesson in currentSessions)
            {
                DateTime mostRecentTimestamp = (from q in db.actions
                                                where q.session_id == sesson.uid
                                                orderby q.timestamp descending
                                                select q.timestamp).FirstOrDefault();

                ParameterizedThreadStart start = new ParameterizedThreadStart(get_lock_data);
                threadArray[cnt] = new Thread(start);
                threadArray[cnt].Start(new LockHunterArgs(sesson.computername , mostRecentTimestamp, sesson.uid));
                cnt++;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < threadArray.Length; i++)
            {
                threadArray[i].Join();
            }
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " Threads have joined");
            //....Snippet of saving the gathered data from the threads to the database
        }
    }
```

**Solution:**

I added a new class. Then looped through my LINQ-to-SQL results to create a list of that new class. Then I base my thread firing from that list instead of the LINQ-to-SQL generated one. All is well. Can anyone explain this?

```
    public class TempSession
    {
        public TempSession(LINQ.session sess)
        {
            this.computername = sess.computername;
            this.timestamp = sess.start_time;
            this.uid = sess.uid;
        }
        public string computername;
        public DateTime timestamp;
        public Guid uid;
    }

    public void HuntLocks()
    {
        //select EventCode,TimeGenerated,Message from Win32_NTLogEvent WHERE logfile='Security' and (EventCode='4800' or EventCode='4801') and TimeGenerated > '20120327 08:08:08'
        // 4800 = locked
        // 4801 = unlocked

        LINQ.Login_ActionsDataContext db = new LINQ.Login_ActionsDataContext();
        List<LINQ.session> currentSessions = (from q in db.sessions
                                              where q.end_time == null
                                              orderby q.computername ascending
                                              select q).ToList();


        // START Solution Changes

        List<TempSession> newCurrentSessions = new List<TempSession>();
        foreach (LINQ.session session in currentSessions)
        {
            newCurrentSessions.Add(new TempSession(session));
        }

        Thread[] threadArray = new Thread[newCurrentSessions.Count];

        // END solution changes

        for (int i = 0; i < newCurrentSessions.Count; i++)
        {
            DateTime mostRecentTimestamp = (from q in db.actions
                                            where q.session_id == newCurrentSessions[i].uid
                                            orderby q.timestamp descending
                                            select q.timestamp).FirstOrDefault();

            ParameterizedThreadStart start = new ParameterizedThreadStart(get_lock_data);
            threadArray[i] = new Thread(start);
            threadArray[i].Start(new LockHunterArgs(newCurrentSessions[i].computername, mostRecentTimestamp, newCurrentSessions[i].uid));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < threadArray.Length; i++)
        {
            threadArray[i].Join();
        }

        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " Threads have joined");

        db.actions.InsertAllOnSubmit(newActions);
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " Found " + newActions.Count.ToString() + " locks");
        db.SubmitChanges();
        newActions = new List<LINQ.action>();

    }
```

Comment: Since we know it is not a closure issue, my gut instincts lead me to think it has to do with making the other Linq To SQL call while iterating though the collection. The new code does not iterate over a linq to SQL generated list while making another linq to sql call. It now uses a simple for loop index counter.

Answer (score 0):

Use a temp variable to store the iterated value:

```
foreach (LINQ.session sesson in currentSessions)
{
     var tempSession = session; // now use tempSession 
     ....
```

This is a known side effect of closure of the iterated value.

Comment: Tried that just now...same results.

Comment: @LanceIngle:  So the _only_ reference to `sesson` is when it's assigned to `tempSession`?  (I see 3)

Comment: are you sure you replaced all referenced to session?

Comment: Yep...I even changed it from a foreach to a for loop. Same results.

Comment: Have you tried assigning `Guid sessionId = sesson.uid` inside the loop and then use `sessionId` in your Linq statement?

Comment: This is not the problem, session is not passed directly as an argument. Its properties are.

Comment: Don't think closure is the issue here. A new LockHunterObject is created each time in the loop and all the types passed into the constructor are value types or immutable so the values are copied implicity each time through the loop

Answer (score 0):

I would say the problem is most likely in what you snipped out.  I was unable to reproduce your issue with this faked data:

```
var guids = Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
    .Select(i => Guid.NewGuid())
    .ToArray();

var currentSessions = Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
    .Select(i => new {computername = "pc" + i})
    .Zip(guids,(a,g) => new {a.computername, uid = g});

var dbactions = Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
    .Select(i => DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1*i))
    .Zip(guids, (t,g) => new {session_id = g, timestamp = t});
```

Given this, can you provide a working example that isn't dependent on any of your local resources?

Comment: I got it to work. I don't understand why it works though. I added a new class. Loop though my LINQ-to-SQL results and create a list of my new class. Then I use the new class in my for loop and all is well. The only thing I can think of is LINQ-to-SQL lists are not thread safe?

Comment: You might have been looping over the closed variable in what you hid from us.  You'd have to show that code for us to know for sure.

Comment: I posted everything (full function) above in the solution.